# How to Integrate a Standalone Django Live Chat App into Main Website Views?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

I'm currently learning Django and have an existing website built in HTML, CSS, JS with a Java Spring backend. I am in the process of migrating it to Django. I've successfully migrated the site and now want to add a new feature: live chat groups between users. I have implemented the live chat functionality as a standalone Django app using Django Channels and Redis, following multiple tutorials. The chat app works as expected when isolated.

The issue I'm facing is how to integrate this chat functionality into the main views of my existing website. Specifically, I want the chat to appear in a small window at the bottom right corner of the screen, similar to how chat features work on Facebook or other social media sites.

I tried using Django's {% include ... %} tag to include the chat functionality in base.html, thinking it would behave similarly to other globally-included elements like the navigation bar. However, this approach doesn't seem to work, and there appears to be some form of communication issue between the two apps.

Here is a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/eddy10957/35b3768b875ac46173bed23f9cb5811b) containing my project structure, base.html, room.html, and index.html for context.